# How to trigger function on vocabulary terms update?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, hooks

Is there a hook that being triggered when any term in taxonomy vocabulary is edited/added/deleted?

I'v tried to use hook_taxonomy_vocabulary_update but no success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I probably should use term_update for this:

```
hook_taxonomy_term_update($term){ 
if ($term->vid == $vid){
// Action
  }
}
```

Or [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)